# "A configuration with this name already exists" error in eclipse run configurations

Tags: java, eclipse

I synced mercurial project, and tried to setup run configurations.

[image]

I found the name has `(1)` attached, and I tried to remove it.

[image]

However, I got `A configuration with this name already exists` error. I checked other configurations, but there was no duplication of Name `Equivalence Checker`.

[image]

[image]

How can I find the existing configuration to remove it?

Comment: There shouldn't be that many kinds of run configurations -- I see Java Applet (empty) and Java Application in your screenshot, and I'm guessing there'll also be JUnit Test and a few others, but most will probably be empty. Have you peeked in all the non-empty ones?

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks for the reply. I need more hints. How do I peek into configuration related info? Do I need to check the files?

Comment: I just mean in the UI. In the "Create, manage, and run configurations" screen, the column at left lists the different types of run configurations ("Java Applet", "Java Application", etc.), each of which can be expanded to show a list of the run configurations of that type.

Comment: @ruakh: I checked to confirm that there is no duplication in Name. I updated my post.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

uncheck the filter: Filter Deleted/Unavailable Projects

[image: debug configurations]

Comment: and you will find the hiden configurations

Comment: For me it was unchecking "Filter Closed Projects".  I had a jar in one project, but the run configurations (somehow) also were associated with the close jsp project that used it.  (I had to re-open the closed project to make it the run configurations usable.)

Comment: Eclipse never ceases to amaze me in how it finds new ways to annoy me. This caused me a headache for several hours until I found this thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a chance you have a launch configuration stored in your workspace as file. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to open the "Open Resource" dialog. Start typing "EquivalenceChecker" and see whether it finds a .launch file with that name in your workspace.

Answer (score 2):

Uncheck all filters under dropdown for "Filter launch configuration"; it is there. If a project is renamed the launch configuration is updated. But when a project is deleted the launch configuration is not deleted. Appear to be a useful feature.