# Eclipse previous configurations

Tags: eclipse

When I try to add a new debug/run configuration in Eclipse and use a name that was used in the past for another project, the Apply and Run buttons are disable. It means that Eclipse never forgets those names

Is there a way to get past, hidden debug/run configurations from Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old launches do not appear in the Run Configurations dialog you will have to delete them manually.

The launch files are stored in the workspace in the '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches' directory.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the official way of getting obsolete launches

See ["A configuration with this name already exists" error in eclipse run configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544725/a-configuration-with-this-name-already-exists-error-in-eclipse-run-configurati)

Near "New lauch configuration", "Duplicate", "Delete" there is a dropdown menu. Uncheck Filter deleted / Unavailable Projects